# Determining if an number is in a list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to find if an number is in the given list but can't figure it out.

I figured out how to do this with just a list(not nested):

```
def find(lst, number):
    if len(lst) == 0: #base case
        return False
    else:
        return number in lst
```

But the problem is with a nested list the above code won't work

What I have so far:

```
def find(lst, number):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return False
    else:
        for i in lst:
            if isinstance(i, list):
                for item in i:
                    if item == number:
                        return True
            elif i == number:
                return True
            else:
                continue

# Nested List (What it should output).
>>> find([1, [3, [4 , [7, 8]], 9]], 8)
True
```

Comment: Why do you have the `base case` comment in a non-recursive algorithm? Further, why do you have that line at all? `return number in lst` works fine with an empty list.

Comment: Your real problem is flattening an irregular nested list; see the dupe.

Comment: lazy (and wrong) way: Convert list to string, remove all `[` and `]`, `eval` it and check `number in the_list`

Comment: While this can be done by flattening, I wouldn't consider it a dupe of a question about flattening.

Comment: @user2357112 No matter how you much you try, you will need to flatten the list or at least walk through it as if it were flatten.

Comment: @JBernardo: at least use `ast.literal_eval()` then. :-P

Comment: @JBernardo You need to walk through all the lists. You do not need to flatten it or pretend it's flattened.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But then I would not win a code golf contest

Comment: @JBernardo: Would you consider the other question a dupe of this one if the other question were posted two months after now? If not, I wouldn't consider this one a dupe; the relation is symmetric. Also, off the top of my head, BFS would solve the problem without flattening the list or walking through it as if it were flattened.

Comment: @user2357112 The other question has all the information needed to solve this problem. Also, if you read the answers below, they are all worse than the best answer from the other question. (And you indeed flattened the list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use recursion:

```
def find(lst, number):
    for item in lst:
        if item == number:
            return True
        elif isinstance(item, list) and find(item, number):
            return True
    return False
```

The key part is here:

```
        elif isinstance(item, list) and find(item, number):
```

If the list element is another list, the algorithm calls itself to determine whether the number is in the sublist. This avoids needing to write nested `for` loops for each of the infinitely many possible levels of nesting the list could have.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than writing out an explicit loop, you could the built in `any` function on a generator expression:

```
def find(lst, num):
    return any(x == num or (isinstance(x, list) and find(x, num)) for x in lst)
```

Or an alternative version that checks the top level list first, before recursing with `any`:

```
def find2(lst, num):
    return num in lst or any(find2(x, num) for x in lst if isinstance(x, list))
```

`any` short circuits if it finds a `True` value, so it should be relatively fast, and it already has the right behavior for empty lists (`any([])` returns `False`) so you don't need any special cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_recursive(num, lst):   
    if isinstance(lst, int):
        return num == lst
    elif not lst:
        return False        
    else:
        first = lst[0]
        rest = lst[1:]
        return find_recursive(num, first) or find_recursive(num, rest)

print(find_recursive(7, [8, [3, [4 , [7, 8]], 9]])) # prints True
print(find_recursive(1, [8, [3, [4 , [7, 8]], 9]])) # prints False
```

Comment: You should check `isinstance` before `not lst` otherwise you may never find the number `0`

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion, that is, replace this piece:

```
if isinstance(i, list):
    for item in i:
        if item == number:
            return True
```

with:

```
if isinstance(i, list):
    if find(i, number:
        return True
```